# XmlDocumentFragment set InnerXml fails with not declared prefix

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML document which basically looks like this:

```
<ArrayOfAspect xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
    <Aspect i:type="TransactionAspect">
        ...
    </Aspect>
    <Aspect i:type="TransactionAspect">
        ...
    </Aspect>
</ArrayOfAspect>
```

And I want to append a new `Aspect` to this list. 
 In order to do so I load this xml from a file, create a `XmlDocumentFragment` and load the new Aspect from a file (which is basically a template I fill with data). Then I fill the document fragment with the new aspect and append it as a child. 
But when I try to set the xml of this fragment it fails because the prefix `i` is not defined.

```
// Load all aspects
var aspectsXml = new XmlDocument();
aspectsXml.Load("aspects.xml");

// Create and fill the fragment
var fragment = aspectsXml.CreateDocumentFragment();
fragment.InnerXml = _templateIFilledWithData; // This fails because i is not defined

// Add the new child
aspectsXml.AppendChild(fragment)
```

This is how the template looks like:

```
<Aspect i:type="TransactionAspect">
    <Value>$VALUES_PLACEHOLDER$</Value>
    ...
</Aspect>
```

Note that I don't want to create POCOs for this and serialize them since the aspects are actualy quite big and nested and I have the same problem with some other xml files as well.

---

EDIT:
jdweng proposed to use XmlLinq (Which is way better than what I used before, so thanks). Here is the code I try to use with XmlLinq (still failing because of undeclared prefix):

```
var aspects = XDocument.Load("aspects.xml");
var newAspects = EXlement.Parse(_templateIFilledWithData); // Fails here - Undeclared prefix 'i'
aspects.Root.add(newAspect);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xml linq :

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;



namespace ConsoleApplication57
{
    class Program
    {
        const string URL = "http://goalserve.com/samples/soccer_inplay.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<ArrayOfAspect xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" +
                    "<Aspect i:type=\"TransactionAspect\">" +
                   "</Aspect>" +
                    "<Aspect i:type=\"TransactionAspect\">" +
                    "</Aspect>" +
                "</ArrayOfAspect>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            XElement root = doc.Root;
            XNamespace nsI = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("i");

            root.Add(new XElement("Aspect", new object[] {
                new XAttribute(nsI + "type", "TransactionAspect"),
                new XElement("Value", "$VALUES_PLACEHOLDER$")
            }));


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't want to manually build the Aspect in code since it's a pretty big object and I have template file which is easy to fill with data.

Comment: You can read in template file and then modif/add elements as needed.  You can use Load(filename) method to read file (instead parse(string).  Then search for element location to modify/add elements.  I just posted sample code so you can see how to gt started.  Your original issue was with namespace 'i' which is in the code posted.

Comment: And how do I add XDocument I created with `XDocument.Parse()` to my container element? - EDIT: Found it myself `XElement.Parse()`

Comment: I would use XElement container = XElement.Load(filename) [or XElement.Parse(string)] instead.  Then adding an XElment to an XElement is simply : root.Add(container);

Comment: I still don't know how to resolve the prefix problem when using a string which is parsed. Can you please update your example to use `XElement.Parse()` instead of building the object in code.

Comment: Iextracting the prefix name here : XNamespace nsI = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("i");  root is the element "ArrayOfAspect".